# dart migrate asks me to run a command after I already ran it

Tags: flutter, dart

I am running

```bash
> dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety

Showing dependencies that are currently not opted in to null-safety.
[✗] indicates versions without null safety support.
[✓] indicates versions opting in to null safety.

All your dependencies declare support for null-safety.

> dart pub upgrade --null-safety
No dependencies changed.
1 package is discontinued.
148 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `dart pub outdated` for more information.

No changes to pubspec.yaml!

> dart pub get
```

And then ran `dart migrate`, got the following output:

```bash
Analyzing project...
[---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\]Bad state: Error: package has unmigrated dependencies.

Before migrating your package, we recommend ensuring that every library it
imports (either directly or indirectly) has been migrated to null safety, so
that you will be able to run your unit tests in sound null checking mode.  You
are currently importing the following non-null-safe libraries:

(a list of files of my project like: package:opengames/presentation/widgets/not_found_screen.dart)

Please upgrade the packages containing these libraries to null safe versions
before continuing.  To see what null safe package versions are available, run
the following command: `dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety`.

To skip this check and try to migrate anyway, re-run with the flag
`--skip-import-check`.
```

Why is this happening? I already ran `dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety`

Comment: "You are currently importing the following non-null-safe libraries:" Are the *only* things listed from the package you're trying to migrate?  Possibly `dart migrate` is confused by the `package:` paths.  If so, then run as `dart migrate --skip-import-check`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have already migrated to a newer version of dart. You can't migrate your projects from the new version, there is literally nothing to migrate to.

If you want to migrate your older projects (which are without null safety) to a new version, your dart version must be older than 2.12.0 version. In this case, consider changing the version in your pubspec.yaml file.

```
   sdk: '>=2.11.0 <3.0.0'
```

Then run this :-
`dart migrate --apply-changes`

Comment: I haven't migrated yet. The project is without null-safety.

My pubspec.yaml shows

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"